# Incorrect onPress Parameter Value When JSX views are Concatinated

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a small list of rows which I rendering in React Native. Each row contains some information and button which performs an operation on the object associated.

To render the rows, I iterate through a list and with each new row, add the JSX markup to an array.

```
for (i = 0; i < this.state.values.length; i++) {
  var theVariable = this.state.values[i].id;
  returnValue.push(
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', borderTopWidth: .5, borderColor: 'grey'}}
      <View style={[s.rowStyle, {justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={s.buttonOutlineActiveRental} underlayColor='transparent'  onPress={() => this._someFunction(theVariable)}>
          <Text style={s.buttonText}>
            Click me!
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The issue is the `theVariable` value of the on press function is incorrect. Through some debugging I've discovered that the `theVariable` is always equal to the `theVariable` in the final row. This leads me to believe that each row is always pointing to the newest version of the variable.

In this case, what is the proper method to pass the parameter through the on press function?

Comment: I believe this happens because you are storing a reference and passing this reference. What is referenced changes every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest changing `var` to `let`. Secondly move the declaration out of the loop.

Next create a new component for the "row". Pass the variable to the row as a prop. This should bind the current value to the component solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! These suggestions worked. Didn't think about making a new component for the row.